# Не работает нейронная сеть

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, нейронные-сети

Код этой нейронной сети взят из книги Тарика Рашида "Создаем нейронную сеть". Этот код не работает.
Вот код:

```
import numpy as np
import scipy.special
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


#определение класса нейронной сети
class Network:

    #инициализировать нейронную сеть
    def __init__(self, inputnodes, hiddennodes, outputnodes, learningrate):
        self.inputnodes = inputnodes
        self.hiddennodes = hiddennodes
        self.outputnodes = outputnodes
        self.learningrate = learningrate

        self.wih = np.random.normal(0.0, pow(self.hiddennodes, -0.5), (self.hiddennodes, self.inputnodes))
        self.who = np.random.normal(0.0, pow(self.outputnodes, -0.5), (self.outputnodes , self.hiddennodes))

        self.activation_func = lambda x: scipy.special.expit(x)

    #тренировка нейронной сети
    def train(self, inputs_list, target_list):
        inputs = np.array(inputs_list, ndmin = 2).T
        targets = np.array(target_list, ndmin = 2).T

        hidden_inputs = np.dot(self.wih, inputs)
        hidden_outputs = self.activation_func(hidden_inputs)

        final_input = np.dot(self.who, hidden_outputs)
        final_outputs = self.activation_func(final_input)

        output_errors = target_list - final_outputs
        hidden_errors = np.dot(self.who.T, output_errors)

        self.who += self.learningrate * np.dot(output_errors * final_outputs * (1.0 - final_outputs), np.transpose(hidden_outputs))
        self.wih += self.learningrate * np.dot(hidden_errors, hidden_outputs * (1.0 - hidden_outputs), np.transpose(inputs))
        print(final_outputs)


    #опрос нейронной сети
    def query(self, inputs_list):
        inputs = np.array(inputs_list, ndmin = 2).T

        hidden_inputs = np.dot(self.wih, inputs)

        final_inputs = np.dot(self.who, hidden_inputs)

        final_outputs = self.activation_func(final_inputs)

        return final_outputs
        

target = [[50, 50]]
inputs = [[150, -10]]

n = Network(2, 2, 2, 0.3)
n.train(inputs, target)
```

Входные данные: [150, -10],
что должно получиться на выходе: [50, 50]

Код ошибки:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 57, in <module>
    n.train(inputs, target)
  File "test.py", line 35, in train
    self.who += self.learningrate * np.dot(output_errors * final_outputs * (1.0 - final_outputs), np.transpose(hidden_outputs))
  File "<__array_function__ internals>", line 6, in dot
ValueError: shapes (2,2) and (1,2) not aligned: 2 (dim 1) != 1 (dim 0)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import numpy as np
import scipy.special
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


# определение класса нейронной сети
class Network:

    # инициализировать нейронную сеть
    def __init__(self, inputnodes, hiddennodes, outputnodes, learningrate):
        self.inputnodes = inputnodes
        self.hiddennodes = hiddennodes
        self.outputnodes = outputnodes
        self.learningrate = learningrate

        self.wih = np.random.normal(
            0.0, pow(self.hiddennodes, -0.5), (self.hiddennodes, self.inputnodes))
        self.who = np.random.normal(
            0.0, pow(self.outputnodes, -0.5), (self.outputnodes, self.hiddennodes))

        # self.activation_func = lambda x: scipy.special.expit(x) scipy не установлен/не устанавливается

    def activation_func(self, x, deriv=False):  # своя сигмоидная функция активации
        y = 1 / (1 + np.exp(-x))
        if deriv == True:
            return 1 * (1 - y)
        return y

    def plot_gr(self, _file: str, errors: list, epochs: list) -> None:
        fig: plt.Figure = None
        ax: plt.Axes = None
        fig, ax = plt.subplots()
        ax.plot(epochs, errors,
                label="learning",
                )
        plt.xlabel('Эпоха обучения')
        plt.ylabel('loss')
        ax.legend()
        plt.savefig(_file)
        print("Graphic saved")
        plt.show()

    # тренировка нейронной сети

    def train(self, inputs_list, target_list):
        epochs = 100
        e = 0
        errors_y = []
        eps_x = []
        for ep in range(epochs):
            for single_arr_ind in range(len(inputs_list)):
                inputs = np.array(inputs_list[single_arr_ind], ndmin=2).T
                targets = np.array(target_list[single_arr_ind], ndmin=2).T

                hidden_inputs = np.dot(self.wih, inputs)
                hidden_outputs = self.activation_func(hidden_inputs)

                final_input = np.dot(self.who, hidden_outputs)
                final_outputs = self.activation_func(final_input)
                ############### Обратное распространение ошибки ##############
                # Q(W) = 1/2 * (targets - out_net)
                # goal: arg min[W] Q(W)

                e = targets - final_outputs
                e = e[0] * e[0]
                output_errors = np.multiply(e, self.activation_func(
                    final_input, deriv=True))  # is dQ/dz2
                # Слаживание ошибки на слое 2 т.е dQ/dz2 для слоя 1 (чтобы он сумировал)
                hidden_errors = np.dot(self.who.T, output_errors)

                self.who += self.learningrate * \
                    np.multiply(output_errors, hidden_outputs.T)
                self.wih += self.learningrate * \
                    np.multiply(hidden_errors, inputs.T)
                print(final_outputs)
                ##############################################################
            e /= 2
            print("error", e)
            eps_x.append(ep)
            errors_y.append(e)
        self.plot_gr('gr.png', errors_y, eps_x)
    # опрос нейронной сети

    def query(self, inputs_list):
        inputs = np.array(inputs_list, ndmin=2).T

        hidden_inputs = self.activation_func(np.dot(self.wih, inputs))

        final_outputs = self.activation_func(np.dot(self.who, hidden_inputs))

        return final_outputs


target = [[0.50, 0.50]]
inputs = [[0.150, -0.10]]

n = Network(2, 2, 2, 0.3)
n.train(inputs, target)
```

[image: gr]

Comment: А что вы изменили в коде? Добавьте это в ответ

Comment: Много всего,функция активации своя,выделение вектора из матрицы обучения и ответов для прямого распространения и обратного,перемножение на производную через multiply где нужно,транспонирование hidden_outputs.T и inputs.T в плюсовании,добавление просчета ошибки целевой функции,график(должен падать),нормализация в единице входных и выходных данных, исправление функции query.